# Create JS - NextStage property on touch devices

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have more than 30 canvas on the DOM with a shape drawn on to the canvas, which will be arranged in overlapping position to make a Pattern, like many triangles will be joined to make a pattern . Please find the below image for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg2wI.png

Ill also be able to draw on any of the canvas and the drawing should replicate on all the shapes. I have used **createjs-nextstage** property to bypass mousedown to underlying canvas. In desktop its working fine but on Touch devices its not working (stagemousemove is not firing).

```
    for (var k = 0; k < currentArray.length; k++) .
    {
         if (k != 0)
         currentArray[k].nextStage = currentArray[k - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Have you added Touch to the top stage? `createjs.Touch.enable(stage);`

Comment: Do i have to enable it for only the top stage or do i have to enable touch for all the stage

Comment: can i update nextstage property on the run. Like i want to disable it on mousedown and re-enable it on mouseup

Comment: You need to enable it for any stage that can receive mouse interaction. If your canvases are all the same size and position, only the top stage needs it. You can update it whenever you want -- the `nextStage` property is checked and applied whenever mouse interaction occurs.